# Jqgrid - Pagination : want to access all options of a dynamic dropdown of all pages in grid. I tried getCell it only gets current pages cell values

Tags: jqgrid

I used Client side Pagination. In 1st page i have **5** rows.

```
var grid = jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
$('#mygrid').jqGrid('getCell',grid[0].Id, 'Color');
```

Here **grid[0].Id** is unique key value of our grid.

The above line returns whole html tag with below options:

```
"<select class="editable" size="1" name="Color" id="xxxxxxxxx_Color" role="select"><option selected="selected" value="Pink">Pink</option><option value="Blue"> Blue</option><option value="Black"> Black</option><option value="Red"> Red</option></select>"
```

when i tried to access **6th** record which is in **another** page:

```
var grid = jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
$('#mygrid').jqGrid('getCell',grid[5].Id, 'Color');
```

Its returning **false**.

I tried **grid[5].Color** which only gets **selected** value option of dropdown. But i want all options of dropdown, just as i got for the 1st record. getCell only works for current page's rows its not working properly for other pages during pagination. Is there any way that i can access all options of dropdown cell of every row in grid.

Comment: You use client side pagination or server side?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. You wrote: "want to access all options of a dynamic dropdown of all pages in grid". The dropdown *in the pager* is just a control and you can access it, modify it independent on jqGrid API. You posted the fragment of the usage `getCell` without any information about jqGrid. Is some row/cell of the grid in editing mode? What do you with jqGrid? Where is the code which creates the grid? Do you use `datatype: "local"` or you loaded data from the server and used `loadonce: true` option? You have to post more code and more information what you do.

Comment: I'm using Client side paging and datatype :'json'.Yes i used loadonce :true. Actual problem is i'm using ajax through which data which is stored in backend gets loaded whenever grid is loaded and the above part of code is accessing a cell(dynamic dropdown). Intial in ColModel it is **" edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: "None:None"} "**. Later in some part of the code i'm populating its options based on some condition. 
 $('#' + rowId + '_Color').append('<option value=' + white + '>' + white  + '</option>');

Comment: If user added any new row and later navigated to another page then previous page's dropdown values of unsaved row's are set to **None**. I used _saverow()_, to save it on client side but its not storing those dropdown cell values. i want these dropdowns to persist data. If these are saved to server then there is no problem but if user navigates to other page before saving them to server then this problem arises.